# C# Skype4COM SendMessage username

Tags: c#, skype, sendmessage, skype4com

I have a problem about Skype4COM SendMessage.

My code is:

```
skype.Attach(5, true);`
skype.SendMessage("CrazyGirl56", "hey");
```

but output:

```
Sent message to crazygirl56.
```

So it sends to crazygirl56, not CrazyGirl56. There is a case problem. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

the Skype user names are not case-sensitive, hence sending message to CrazyGirl56 or crazygirl56 is the same